# How to detect if the browser has Popup Blocker active

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

As I mention in title I not able to detect if the browser has popup blocker active

I tried with Vaadin versions:

14.2.0
14.3.0
14.4.0
14.9.6

Also on Vaadin V24 I didn't saw anything related with this kind of configurations.

With the help of ChatGPT also was not successful because told me to use PopupBlockerDetector class but this class doesn't exists.

Few examples I tried:

```
  String popupUrl = "https://www.example.com/popup";
    String windowName = "popup";
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    String features = String.format("width=%d,height=%d", width, height);
    Window window = UI.getCurrent().getPage().open(popupUrl, windowName, features);

    if (window == null || window.closed || !window.isResizable()) {
        // popup was blocked or closed by the user
        Notification.show("Popup is blocked!");
    }
```

Other example:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.add(new Span("Test span"));
        UI.getCurrent().add(dialog);
        Notification.show(MessageFormat.format("Dialog is opened? {0}", dialog.isOpened()));
```

Browsers with the issue: Safari, Firefox.

Comment: Maybe this is an X-Y-Problem? What kind of "popup" and what browser/setup does not work? Questions like this are border-line to being closed, so it's better to show what you have tried or even better provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the second example, you should see a dialog if you replace `UI.getCurrent().add(dialog)` with `dialog.open()`; dialogs are no popup-window, but just some dom content and should always show regardless of settings in the browser.